# Tag formatting options options for html and php in Visual Studio IDE

Tags: php, visual-studio, code-formatting

How can I modify the html default code formatting in Visual Studio on a per-tag basis? When I choose `Tools > Text Editor > HTML`, there isn't a Formatting option. That's where the Tag Specific Options button usually resides. There is a `Tools > Text Editor > HTML (Web Forms) > Formatting > Tag Specific` button.

To slightly complicate my question, I *really* want tag specific options for PHP files and I'm using PHP Tools. But even if I disable PHP Tools, close my project, and open an html file, the Format Document command results in a formatting style I dislike.